# iteration over every element of 1d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

From an `nc` file I've read variables which are in the form of arrays. Now I've performed a calculation with the first element of all these variables and created a new variable. I want to repeat the same set of calculations for each element in the initial arrays without changing the code for the calculation which I have made taking a single point into consideration.

I've tried `zip` and `nditer` but in both cases the if statements in variable `a` are to be changed to `.any()` or `.all()`. I can't do either because I want the if statement to take into consideration only a single point and not the entire array.

```
T = AD06_ALL_OMNI.variables['A_TEMP'][:][0]  
REL_HUM = AD06_ALL_OMNI.variables['HUMIDITY'][:][0]
AIR_PRES = AD06_ALL_OMNI.variables['A_PRES'][:][0]
a = T-29.65
#masking of values so that division by 0 is avoided
if a!=0.0:
    exponent1 = math.exp(17.67*T-0.16/a)   
q = REL_HUM*exponent1/(26.3*AIR_PRES)  
deltaq = 0.98*qs-q
print (deltaq)
```

I need `a` to be computed for each point so that `deltaq` is found out for the same point taking values of T, `REL_HUM`, and `AIR_PRES` from the corresponding points. All variables are of same size (1d arrays). Please help!

Comment: You can use a loop if the lengths of T, REL_HUM and AIR_PRES are same.

Comment: When I am using a for loop to zip the variables and then start iteration, the if statements are not working. The code then asks a condition .any() or .all() for within if statement. But this condition would mean if all values in the array 'a' is not equal to 0 only then compute the exponent1. I need this condition for 'a' to work only for single points.

Comment: You can loop over all the values of 'a' and check for 0 for each value in the array

Comment: are all arrays of the same length ? What does `a` signify? does it change or is it always `AD06_ALL_OMNI.variables['A_TEMP'][:][0] - 29.65`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for var in range(0, length(AD06_ALL_OMNI.variables['A_TEMP'][:])-1):
    T = AD06_ALL_OMNI.variables['A_TEMP'][:][var]  
    REL_HUM = AD06_ALL_OMNI.variables['HUMIDITY'][:][var]
    AIR_PRES = AD06_ALL_OMNI.variables['A_PRES'][:][var]
    a = T-29.65
    #masking of values so that division by 0 is avoided
    count = 0
    for element in a:
        if element!=0.0:
            exponent1 = math.exp(17.67*T[count] -0.16/element)   
        q = REL_HUM[count]*exponent1/(26.3*AIR_PRES[count] )  
        deltaq = 0.98*qs-q
        print (deltaq)
        count = count + 1
```

Assuming that all the arrays are of the same length(it doesn't make sense if you don't have air pressure, air temperature and humidity of equal lengths)you can use a loop to iterate over all the values of a, check for 0 for each value and calculate and print deltaq for each point. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I used the loop and it worked. But now, I need the value of deltaq to be stored somewhere in the form of an array. I'm only getting a single value right now. should I use np.asarray??

Comment: Also, I added var in [ ] brackets with each of the variable names like T[var], REL_HUM[var], and AIR_PRES[var]. Only then it worked.

Comment: You can keep appending to a list or can use numpy functions also. You mentioned that T is a 1D array. So, if you are using T[var], it will be a single value and so a will also be a single value and not an array. So, according to the details in the question, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should have mentioned if you wanted to calculate deltaq for each value in T, REL_HUM, and AIR_PRES. The correct way to calculate deltaq will be to use a count variable and calculate deltaq for each value in the 1D arrays. I have edited the answer. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: yes. Thank you so much, it helps. I want the calculation within the loop to be performed with each of the values of the intial variables and finally the variables I get will also be an array. So, at the end of the computation I'll have to store each of these single values computed using single points of initial variables in an array.